# Citrix GoToWebinar API Response with teodortalov/citrix

Tags: php, rest, citrix

Thank you for taking the time to review my question.

I have been trying to implement the Citrix Go2Webinar Api and found this nice framework: https://github.com/teodortalov/citrix

I have successfully registered users, but I can't figure out how to get the response from the API.

```
public function user_registration($user, $webinar_id)
        {
            $client = new \Citrix\Authentication\Direct([$this->api_key]);
            $client->auth($this->username, $this->password);

            $webinar = new \Citrix\GoToWebinar($client);

            $registration = array('firstName' => $user['first_name'], 'lastName' => $user['last_name'], 'email' => $user['email']);

            $registrant = $webinar->register($webinar_id, $registration);

            return $registrant;
        }
```

The response I get looks like a bunch of protected variables. My question shouldn't I be able to call a method to get the formatted response which looks like what the Citrix API expects to return:

```
{
   "registrantKey": 0,
   "joinUrl": "string"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

those methods are in consumer.php

```
$registrant = $webinar->register($webinar_id, $registration);
$myJoinUrl = $registration->getJoinUrl();
$myRegistrantKey = $registration->getId();
```